# activity with one fragment on back arrow press first activity is open

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to open the parent activity on device backpress without going to the other opened activity in between

tried override OnBackPress().

```
var intent = Intent(this, HomeActivty::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

I am not getting the parent activity on single click of device backpress still

Comment: try  `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)`

Comment: After starting an activity use ```finish()```. Avoid finish in the first activity. ```finish()``` will remove other activities from activity stack and you can simply use your back button to go to first activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution for not looping the activity/fragment while onbackpress by following code -
 fun onBack(){
      var intent = Intent(this,HomeActivty::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
        finishAffinity()
    }

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

> `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`